# Fatal Error while running a CMS program

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

i get this error while running my program.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   CarModel::InsertCar() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CoffeeWebsite\Controller\CarController.php:119 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CoffeeWebsite\CarAdd.php(43):
>   CarController->InsertCar() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CoffeeWebsite\Controller\CarController.php on line 119

```
//Source code for CarModel and CarController
 <?php

    require ("Entities/CarEntity.php");

    //Contains database related code for the Car page.
    class CarModel {

        //Get all car types from the database and return them in an array.
        function GetCarTypes() {
            require 'Credentials.php';

            //Open connection and Select database.   
            $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $passwd) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $sql = mysqli_select_db($con,$database);
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT type FROM car") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $types = array();

            //Get data from database.
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                array_push($types, $row[0]);
            }

            //Close connection and return result.
            mysqli_close($con);
            return $types;
        }

        //Get carEntity objects from the database and return them in an array.
        function GetCarByType($type) {
            require 'Credentials.php';

            //Open connection and Select database.     
           $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $passwd) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $sql = mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE type LIKE '$type'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $carArray = array();

            //Get data from database.
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $name = $row[1];
                $type = $row[2];
                $price = $row[3];
                $colour = $row[4];
                $details = $row[5];
                $image = $row[6];
                $review = $row[7];

                //Create car objects and store them in an array.
                $car = new CarEntity(-1, $name, $type, $price, $colour, $details, $image, $review);
                array_push($carArray, $car);
            }
            //Close connection and return result
            mysqli_close($con);
            return $carArray;
        }
    function GetCarByID($id)
    {
      require 'Credentials.php';

            //Open connection and Select database.     
           $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $passwd) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $sql = mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE id=$id";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));


            //Get data from database.
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $name = $row[1];
                $type = $row[2];
                $price = $row[3];
                $colour = $row[4];
                $details = $row[5];
                $image = $row[6];
                $review = $row[7];

                //Create car 
                $car = new CarEntity($id, $name, $type, $price, $colour, $details, $image, $review);

            }
            //Close connection and return result
            mysqli_close($con);
            return $car;  
    }
    }
    function InsertCar(CarEntity $car) {
            $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO car
                              (name, type, price,colour,details,image,review)
                              VALUES
                              ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->name),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->type),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->price),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->colour),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->details),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string("Images/Coffee/" . $car->image),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->review));
            $this->PerformQuery($query);
        }

        function UpdateCar($id, CarEntity $car) {
            $query = sprintf("UPDATE car
                                SET name = '%s', type = '%s', price = '%s', colour = '%s',
                                details = '%s', image = '%s', review = '%s'
                              WHERE id = $id",
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->name),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->type),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->price),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->colour),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->details),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string("Images/Coffee/" . $car->image),
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($car->review));

            $this->PerformQuery($query);
        }

        function DeleteCar($id) {
            $query = "DELETE FROM car WHERE id = $id";
            $this->PerformQuery($query);
        }

        function PerformQuery($query) {
            require ('Credentials.php');
            $con=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $passwd) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

            //Execute query and close connection
            mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            mysqli_close($con);
        }



    ?>



 <?php

    require ("Model/CarModel.php");

    //Contains non-database related function for the Coffee page
    class CarController {

        function CreateCarDropdownList() {
            $carModel = new CarModel();
            $result = "<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
                        Please select a type: 
                        <select name = 'types' >
                            <option value = '%' >All</option>
                            " . $this->CreateOptionValues($carModel->GetCarTypes()) .
                    "</select>
                         <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search' />
                        </form>";

            return $result;
        }

        function CreateOptionValues(array $valueArray) {
            $result = "";

            foreach ($valueArray as $value) {
                $result = $result . "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
            }

            return $result;
        }

        function CreateCarTables($types)
        {
            $carModel = new CarModel();
            $carArray = $carModel->GetCarByType($types);
            $result = "";

            //Generate a carTable for each carEntity in array
            foreach ($carArray as $key => $car) 
            {
                $result = $result .
                        "<table class = 'carTable'>
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan='6' width = '150px' ><img runat = 'server' src = '$car->image' /></th>
                                <th width = '75px' >Name: </th>
                                <td>$car->name</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Type: </th>
                                <td>$car->type</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Price: </th>
                                <td>$car->price</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Colour: </th>
                                <td>$car->colour</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Details: </th>
                                <td>$car->details</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
    <th>Review: </th>                            
    <td colspan='2' >$car->review</td>
                            </tr>


                         </table>";
            }        
            return $result;

        }

        function GetImages() {
            //Select folder to scan
            $handle = opendir("Images/Coffee");

            //Read all files and store names in array
            while ($image = readdir($handle)) {
                $images[] = $image;
            }

            closedir($handle);

            //Exclude all filenames where filename length < 3
            $imageArray = array();
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                if (strlen($image) > 2) {
                    array_push($imageArray, $image);
                }
            }

            //Create <select><option> Values and return result
            $result = $this->CreateOptionValues($imageArray);
            return $result;
        }

        //<editor-fold desc="Set Methods">
        function InsertCar() {


            $name = $_POST["txtName"];
            $type = $_POST["ddlType"];
            $price = $_POST["txtPrice"];
            $colour = $_POST["txtColour"];
            $details = $_POST["txtDetails"];
            $image = $_POST["ddlImage"];
            $review = $_POST["txtReview"];

            $car = new CarEntity(-1, $name, $type, $price, $colour, $details, $image, $review);
            $carModel = new CarModel();
            $carModel->InsertCar($car);
        }

        function UpdateCar($id) {

        }

        function DeleteCar($id) {

        }
        //</editor-fold>

        //<editor-fold desc="Get Methods">
        function GetCarById($id) {
            $carModel = new CarModel();
            return $carModel->GetCarById($id);
        }

        function GetCarByType($type) {
            $carModel = new CarModel();
            return $carModel->GetCarByType($type);
        }

        function GetCarTypes() {
            $carModel = new CarModel();
            return $carModel->GetCarTypes();
        }
        //</editor-fold>
    }




    ?>
```

Comment: You have 2 `}` above the InsertCar function, this is closing off the CarModel class

Comment: thanks a lot man....but nw i get this error
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CoffeeWebsite\Model\CarModel.php on line 95

and this
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CoffeeWebsite\Model\CarModel.php on line 132

Comment: In your InsertCar function in CarModel class, you're using the procedural style for mysqli_real_escape_string, this takes 2 arguments, the link and the string. so you need to pass the connection into InsertCar and use it. [See docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Ideally you want to refactor your code such that you 1. use MySQLi Prepared statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). 2. you want to pass in the query and arguments into PerformQuery and dynamically generate the perpared statement in there since  thats where you connect/ and query.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment.

First you want to use Prepared statements. Here is an example:

```
/* Connection */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* Check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE...")) 
{
    /* Bind your params */
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);

    /* Error handling if execute failed */
    if (!$stmt->execute()) 
    {
        die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
}
else 
{
    /* Error handling if Prepare failed */
    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($DBConnect->error));
}

$stmt->close();
```

Read more about returning result [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Now since you want to pass in args from your functions which are unknown to the PerformQuery function, you'll want to dynamically generate the Bind Params for use of using prepared statements. I've done something similar for dynamically generating the Bind Params using Reflection.

If you pass an Args value into the PerformQuery function you could have a function that looks like this:

```
public function PerformQuery($sql, $args = null)
{
    /* Connection */
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* Check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) 
    {
        /* Bind your params dynamically */
        if (isset($args)) 
        {
            $method = new \ReflectionMethod('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param');
            $method->invokeArgs($stmt, $this->refValues($args));
        }

        /* Error handling if execute failed */
        if (!$stmt->execute()) 
        {
            die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        /* Error handling if Prepare failed */
        die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

For the dynamic binding to work you'll also need the following function

```
private function refValues($arr)
{
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
    {
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        return $refs;
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Now from your other methods, for example DeleteCar you'd pass in the query and args as follows:

```
public  function DeleteCar($id) 
{
    $query = "DELETE FROM car WHERE id = ?"; // ? to show where mysqli will bind
    $args = array('i', $id); // i means an int
    $this->PerformQuery($query, args);
}
```

Using prepared statements will make your code much more secure and dynamically binding the variants in the Preform Query function means that you don't have to completely refactor your code to pass a connection around so you can use mysqli_real_escape_string.

Good luck :)